# Why am I getting Variable Declaration error with JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe

My end goal is to have the user enter the names of three runners and the time they complete the run in. The it will organize the runners based on fiunish times and I would like to print the results to a table, but when I compile at the end I get the following error;

```
error: variable declaration not allowed here
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

when I run the JFrame code separately it works just fine, but then when I compile all of the code together I am getting the above error.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JTableCreatingDemo {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    String runner1, runner2, runner3;
    double runTime1, runTime2, runTime3;

    //Get the names and run time of each runner 
    runner1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name of runner 1"); //runner1
    runTime1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter runtime of runner 1 in minutes")); //runTime1
    while (runTime1<0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Entry");
            runtTime1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter runtime of runner 1 in minutes \nEntery format should be MM.SS"));
        }

    runner2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name of runner 2"); //runner2
    runTime2 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter runtime of runner 2 in minutes")); //runTime2
    while (runTime2<0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Entry");
            runtTime2 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter runtime of runner 2 in minutes \nEntery format should be MM.SS"));
        }

    runner3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name of runner 3"); //runner3
    runtime3 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter runtime of runner 3 in minutes")); //runTime3
    while (runTime3<0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Entry");
            runtTime3 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter runtime of runner 3 in minutes \nEntery format should be MM.SS"));
        }

    //Sort the runners by their respective run times
    if(runtime1<=runtime2 && runtime1<=runtime3) //runner1 is the fastest
    {
        if(runtime2<=runtime3)
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            Object rowData[][] = { { runner1, runtime1 + " minutes", "-" },
                { runner2, runtime2 + " minutes", (runtime2-runtime1) },
                {runner3, runtime3 + " minutes", (runtime3-runTime1)} };
            Object columnNames[] = { "Runners Name", "Finish Time", "Differnce" };
            JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setSize(300, 150);
            frame.setVisible(true);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget `{` `}` for you last `if`?

Comment: You forgot to surround the section of code following your `if` statement with brackets

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes I delve so deep into what could cause a problem that I forget the look at the basics!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and it should work. I just fixed the bracket errors :)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JTableCreatingDemo {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    String runner1, runner2, runner3;
    double runTime1, runTime2, runTime3;

    //Get the names and run time of each runner 
    runner1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name of runner 1"); //runner1
    runTime1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter runtime of runner 1 in minutes")); //runTime1
    while (runTime1<0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Entry");
            runtTime1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter runtime of runner 1 in minutes \nEntery format should be MM.SS"));
        }

    runner2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name of runner 2"); //runner2
    runTime2 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter runtime of runner 2 in minutes")); //runTime2
    while (runTime2<0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Entry");
            runtTime2 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter runtime of runner 2 in minutes \nEntery format should be MM.SS"));
        }

    runner3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name of runner 3"); //runner3
    runtime3 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter runtime of runner 3 in minutes")); //runTime3
    while (runTime3<0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Entry");
            runtTime3 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter runtime of runner 3 in minutes \nEntery format should be MM.SS"));
        }

    //Sort the runners by their respective run times
    if(runtime1<=runtime2 && runtime1<=runtime3) //runner1 is the fastest
    {
        if(runtime2<=runtime3) 
           {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            Object rowData[][] = { { runner1, runtime1 + " minutes", "-" },
                { runner2, runtime2 + " minutes", (runtime2-runtime1) },
                {runner3, runtime3 + " minutes", (runtime3-runTime1)} };
            Object columnNames[] = { "Runners Name", "Finish Time", "Differnce"
           }
 };
            JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setSize(300, 150);
            frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    }
    }
```